# Using EcliplseLink JPA how can I disable all the relationship lookups when persisting an object?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When I persist an object with a foreign key, I see in the logs that eclipselink goes off and does a verification query, like this:
I also see that eclipselink finds this object and binds it. I don't want it to do either of these things.

Basically I am trying to save object A, and A has a relationship with object B. When I go to insert a new A, all I have is the ID for B, not an instance of class B, and I am not interested in obtaining an instance of B in this case.

Something like this:

```
String b_id = "12345";
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.setId(b_id);
a.setB(b);


//begin tran
try {
    em.persist(a);
//commit
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //rollback
}
```

which causes this in the logs:

```
Execute query DoesExistQuery(referenceClass=B)
SELECT ID FROM B WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [12345]
```

Now I want to insert A without Eclipselink going to verify if there exists a B with this Id, and I don't want it to bind this B to the field of A which is an instance of B.

I don't want Eclipselink adding this overhead to the insert, because the database is going to be doing this validation before the insert anyways, and I don't need an actual instance of B in this case.

Any reply is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally the role of the [`EntityManager.getReference()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) method: it creates and returns a proxy to the entity having the given class and ID, without hitting the database:

```
A a = new A();
B b = em.getReference(B.class, bId);
a.setB(b);
```

I have no experience with EclipseLink though, so I don't know when exactly is this query executed.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I still see the select and the bind in the log but I do not see "Execute query DoesExistQuery" any longer, so I assume we are in the clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using getReference is probably best.  You could also customize your DoesExist policy on your descriptor (@ExistenceChecking(ASSUME_EXISTENCE)).

Answer (score 1):

The cascade annotation on A <-> B relation determines that extra call. Probably you have CascadeType.ALL and what you want is CascadeType.REFRESH and CascadeType.REMOVE only.